# How do I display a database table in HTML table dynamically?

Tags: php, html

I want to display the following database table in an HTML table with outlet_name as rows and compet_product_name as columns. I, however, do not want the compet_product_name to repeat themselves. They should be distinct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8oKj.png

[image]

Comment: Please show you HTML and Database table With code

Comment: The database table is in the link provided

Comment: Hi & welcome to the SO. Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Thanks. This will help me get a working solution